# SVN removed files

Tags: windows, svn

I renamed some files in my project, changing case of some characters in file names

```
main.cpp -> Main.cpp
```

And then I wrote the changes to SVN repo. It prompted me to delete files (e.g. main.cpp) and add (e.g. Main.cpp).
I removed low case files(e.g. main.cpp), but up case files (e.g. Main.cpp) was not added, because they was deleted from the disk.

Now, It is a great pain to restore them. I know that windows file system is not case sensitive, however I did not expect that people who wrote svn for windows made such an awful mistake.

Could somebody suggest me any svn distributions for windows which do not have such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> svn distributions for windows which do not have such issues

They will all behave the same, as this is **expected behaviour** on windows. When you want SVN to preserve your local file, then you have to tell it to:
`svn rm --keep-local file.to.delete.in.repo`, otherwise it will simply try to delete the file. And Windows will happily delete your `Main.cpp` when you tell it to delete `main.cpp`.